# Can't serialize/deserialize classes implementing interface with GSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm trying to serialize a class that has a list of interface objects. I have added a type register that should get it to work, however I'm out of luck as it's still not working. Code below.

Rule:

```
public interface Rule extends Serializable {

    public String getName();

    public boolean setData(String data);
    public String getData();

}
```

RuleAbstract:

```
public abstract class RuleAbstract implements Rule {

    private static transient final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public RuleAbstract(){ }

}
```

ActionRule:

```
public interface ActionRule extends Rule {

    public void doAction(Player player);

}
```

One of the ActionRule classes:

```
public class DoCmd extends RuleAbstract implements ActionRule {

    private static transient final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static DoCmd i = new DoCmd();
    public static DoCmd get() { return i; }

    private String cmd;

    public DoCmd(){

    }

    @Override
    public void doAction(Player player) {
        if(this.cmd == null) return;
        MixinCommand.get().dispatchCommand(player, this.cmd);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean setData(String data) {
        /** Must start with leading slash */
        if(!data.startsWith("/")) return false;
        this.cmd = data;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String getData() {
        return this.cmd;
    }

}
```

And finally, the class that must be serialized & deserialized:

```
public class RuleList {

    List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<Rule>();

}
```

All of this should work with my type adapter:

```
public class AdapterRule implements JsonDeserializer<Rule>, JsonSerializer<Rule> {

    private static AdapterRule i = new AdapterRule();
    public static AdapterRule get() { return i; }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Rule src, Type typeOf, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        if(src.getData() != null || src.getData() != ""){
            return new JsonPrimitive(String.format("%s %s", src.getName(), src.getData()));
        }
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public Rule deserialize(JsonElement src, Type typeOf, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String splitted[] = src.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString().split(" ");
        if(splitted.length == 1){
            return RuleAbstract.getRule(splitted[0]);
        } else {
            String tempData = "";
            for(String data : splitted){
                tempData = tempData + " " + data;
            }
            Rule rule = RuleAbstract.getRule(splitted[0]);
            rule.setData(tempData);
            return rule;
        }
    }

}
```

Could someone PLEASE point out what I'm doing wrong? Error I'm receiving:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface some.package.Rule. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

Comment: Too much code + missing some code pieces. The exception is telling you that Gson cannot instantiate interface unless its subclass constructor is registered using `InstanceCreator`. It would be better if you'd provide both JSON and full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv what code are you missing? I'm fairly sure I provided everything needed... I'll edit it asap with the full exception stacktrace. Also, as you can see in my code provided, I have added an adapter for GSON and the Rule classes, wouldn't this be enough to make it work?

Comment: It has undeclared symbols. Anyway. An example JSON would give a hint if you can restore the original type because you must have it somewhere (unless `DoCmd` is the only implementator). At least, have you registered your `JsonDeserializer`?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Yes, the deserializer/serializer is registered. Here is the full exception stacktrace: https://hastebin.com/azowidiyuc.swift I am trying to end up with a JSON looking like this: https://hastebin.com/yeduvabesu.json

Comment: Well, you don't seem to have the deserializer registered. Another point: this is not a trivial JSON having duplicate keys `DoCmd` within the same JSON object. Do you generate these JSON documents or you get them from elsewhere?

Comment: They are saved either flatfile files, or in a MongoDB database. How would duplicate of `DoCmd` be an issue? It's a list, not a HashMap, that shouldn't cause duplicate problems, should it? I am registered the serializer/deserializer here: https://hastebin.com/kejuxaboja.css This gets called when the program executes. I have always done it like this and it works as it should in all previous projects.

Comment: Well, this is what I was talking about when you didn't provide enough code in your question... 1) _How would duplicate of DoCmd be an issue?_ -- Gson does not support it without custom type adapters. 2) _It's a list, not a HashMap_ -- No, the JSON you provided has a JSON object with duplicate keys, not a JSON array. 3) `.registerTypeAdapter(AdapterRule.class, AdapterRule.get())` --  This is just wrong. Just replace `AdapterRule.class` to `Rule.class` since Gson binds _the left class_ using _the right JSON (de)serializer_ (how it could know the `Rule` interface deserialization strategy?).

Answer (score 0):

The GSON deserializer needs a default constructor on the class being deserialized, i.e. `RuleList`.

If you can't provide a default constructor then you need to register an `InstanceCreator` that will provide a new RuleList to the deserializer.

Comment: Gson totally ignores constructors by design.